# How to count duration between different overlapping occurrences in a csv file - pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following DataFrame from a csv file.

| Time | User | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/22/2021 10:58:08 AM | User A | Open document |
| 10/22/2021 11:17:54 AM | User B | Open document |
| 10/22/2021 11:18:41 AM | User C | Open document |
| 10/22/2021 11:19:49 AM | User C | Close document |
| 10/22/2021 11:23:12 AM | User B | Close document |
| 10/22/2021 11:23:24 AM | User A | Close document |
| 10/24/2021 3:50:12 PM | User A | Open document |
| 10/24/2021 3:50:18 PM | User B | Open document |
| 10/24/2021 3:51:02 PM | User A | Close document |
| 10/24/2021 3:51:07 PM | User A | Open document |
| 10/24/2021 3:51:23 PM | User C | Open document |
| 10/24/2021 3:58:19 PM | User C | Close document |
| 10/24/2021 3:58:36 PM | User A | Close document |
| 10/24/2021 3:58:37 PM | User A | Open document |
| 10/24/2021 4:15:55 PM | User B | Close document |
| 10/24/2021 4:17:30 PM | User A | Close document |
| 10/24/2021 4:17:31 PM | User C | Open document |
| 10/24/2021 4:19:38 PM | User C | Close document |

The desired output would be how long did each user work alone (strictly just by him/herself) and how long did they worked together in different combinations. Work is considered as time between the "Open document" and "Close document".
Expected output is as follows:

| Time_spent | Users |
| --- | --- |
| x(hours) : y(minutes) : z(seconds) | User A |
| x(hours) : y(minutes) : z(seconds) | User B |
| x(hours) : y(minutes) : z(seconds) | User C |
| x(hours) : y(minutes) : z(seconds) | Users A and B |
| x(hours) : y(minutes) : z(seconds) | Users A and C |
| x(hours) : y(minutes) : z(seconds) | Users B and C |
| x(hours) : y(minutes) : z(seconds) | Users A, B and C |

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This direction is very memory inefficient, and haven't tested the results (it's complicated), but let me know what you think about it:

A. create a df where every row contains the open and close of every user:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df.sort_values(['User', 'Time'], inplace=True)

close_and_open_df = \
pd.concat([df[df['Description']=='Open document'].reset_index(drop=True),
           df[df['Description']=='Close document'].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1) \
           [['Time', 'User']].iloc[:,:-1]
close_and_open_df.columns = ['open', 'close', 'user']
```

B. add a column of an array of all the seconds between open and close

```
close_and_open_df['ts_array'] = \
[pd.date_range(start=x[0], end=x[1], freq='s') 
 for x in zip(close_and_open_df['open'], close_and_open_df['close'])]
```

C. explode that column to create a row per user per second

```
all_ts_df = close_and_open_df.explode('ts_array')
```

D. group by second to get all users in that second:

```
grouped_1 = \
pd.DataFrame(all_ts_df.groupby('ts_array').apply(lambda df: tuple(sorted(list(df['user'].unique()))))).reset_index()
```

E. group by combination to get number of seconds:

```
grouped_1.groupby(0).size()
```

Comment: I tested your code on my sample DataFrame and it works great, thank you very much!
However, when I test in on my actual DataFrame, I get an error: "ValueError: Neither `start` nor `end` can be NaT". I believe this is due to bad data from my DataFrame, e.g. "User A Close doc" is not recorded, so I have two "User A Open doc" in a row. Do you know how to solve or bypass this problem?

Comment: it really depends on what logic you want to implement, my suggestion is to look into the results of stage A and think what you want to do. one direction is to filter out cases without close and open